# how to fetch single value from database instead of array in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

I am using following query.

```
$profile_status= DB::table('profiles')->select('profile_status')->where('id',$user_id)->pluck('profile_status');
```

Its returning : ["created","created"]

I want to get only value stored in row.like : created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use select and pluck together in the same query. You can try this:

```
$profile_status=DB::table('profiles')->where('id', $user_id)->first()->profile_status;
```